# Is there any way to simplify following summation?

Tags: summation

Is there any way to simplify following summation?

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2(k+1)^2}$$

Comment: **Hint:** After a bit of [partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition), see [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Comment: For $n<\infty$, see [generalized harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{k^2 (k+1)^2} = \left(\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}\right)^{2} = \frac{1}{k^2} + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} - \frac{2}{k} + \frac{2}{k+1}
\end{align}
for which
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2 (k+1)^2} &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2} + \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k^2} + 2 \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k} - 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \\
&= -1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k^2} + \frac{2}{n+1} - 2 \\
&= -2 - \left( \frac{1}{n+1} - 1\right)^2 + \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{2}{k^2}\\
&= - \frac{3n^2 + 4n +2}{(n+1)^2} + \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{2}{k^2} \\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{3n^2 + 4n +2}{(n+1)^2} - \psi_{1}(n+2)
\end{align}
where $\psi_{1}(x)$ is the derivative of the digamma function.

Answer (score 0):

By induction it can be shown that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \frac {n}{n+1}$$

That might be a first step